# Who does the type checking for golang in visual studo code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

**Edit**: Please be so kind and *read* the question before you judge it. Answers like "It typechecks your code" are not helpful and only show that you have not understood the question. This question is *not* about a typo, it is about the (partial) implementation of the semantics of golang.

---

I am starting to learn go and thus I am trying to explore the basics of the language.

If I use this statement:

```golang
    fmt.Println(1 + true)
```

in Visual Studio Code, I get "invalid operation: 1 + true (mismatched types untyped int and untyped bool)", **before** running my program.

I am totally fine with the error message, but I am wondering how VSC knows that before compilation.

Go's **parser** should be happy with this line, since there is no type restriction (like allowing only numeric expressions as operands of "+") in go's [grammar](https://golang.org/ref/spec):

```
Expression = UnaryExpr | Expression binary_op Expression .
UnaryExpr  = PrimaryExpr | unary_op UnaryExpr .

binary_op  = ... |  add_op | ... .
add_op     = "+" | ... .
```

So, I am wondering, what is going on here? is there a separate step of type-checking in go's compiler that VSC uses or did VSC write its own type checker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VSCode uses a [language server](https://microsoft.github.io/language-server-protocol/) for language-aware IDE features like autocompletion, diagnostics, jump-to definition, etc.

For Go, the language server implementation is [gopls](https://blog.golang.org/gopls-vscode-go). If you're *really* curious, feel free to check out the source code of the [vscode-go extension](https://github.com/golang/vscode-go), however if you're just learning Go perhaps you have better things to do :-)

The extension is written in TypeScript (like most of VSCode), though gopls [is written in Go](https://github.com/golang/tools/tree/master/gopls). It uses Go tooling which supports parsing and type checking Go code with the [go/types package](https://golang.org/pkg/go/types/). You are correct that for this specific error, type checking is required; just parsing is insufficient.

Here's a basic example of using `go/types` to typecheck Go code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/importer"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
    "go/types"
    "log"
)

const hello = `package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
        fmt.Println("Hello, world")
}`

func main() {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()

    // Parse the input string, []byte, or io.Reader,
    // recording position information in fset.
    // ParseFile returns an *ast.File, a syntax tree.
    f, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, "hello.go", hello, 0)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // parse error
    }

    // A Config controls various options of the type checker.
    // The defaults work fine except for one setting:
    // we must specify how to deal with imports.
    conf := types.Config{Importer: importer.Default()}

    // Type-check the package containing only file f.
    // Check returns a *types.Package.
    pkg, err := conf.Check("cmd/hello", fset, []*ast.File{f}, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err) // type error
    }

    fmt.Printf("Package  %q\n", pkg.Path())
    fmt.Printf("Name:    %s\n", pkg.Name())
    fmt.Printf("Imports: %s\n", pkg.Imports())
    fmt.Printf("Scope:   %s\n", pkg.Scope())
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!! I am actually **really** curious and it will take me a bit to digest your answer, but it is quite possible that I will have follow-up questions.

Comment: Actually, there must be something more going on, since I hadn't installed gopl and after doing so, the errormessage in vscode changed to "cannot convert 1 (untyped int constant) to untyped bool" - which is just what I get, when I insert the faulty statement into the program string of your very helpful code example and then having the errormessage printed out by `fmt.Printf("ERROR: %T\t %v\n", err, err)`. However, I now know where I could find this out, namely via the source code of the vscode-go extension that you provided.

Comment: @tiffi: gopls became default in vscode only recently (see the blog post linked in my answer). It's possible that you originally saw what the older language server reports. Going forward, gopls is going to be the language server for the vscode Go extension. You can configure it too -- see https://github.com/golang/vscode-go/blob/master/docs/settings.md#settings-for-gopls

Comment: My question *behind* my question was how often the syntax/semantics of a language should be defined given that languages evolve and consistency is desirable. Am I right in assuming that the move to gopls is driven exactly by those kind of concerns?

Comment: @tiffi: for all the reasons for gopls, read the blog post and the links from there - there are several reasons (for example, understanding modules). In Go, tooling is standardized - the `go/types` package is part of the standard library and is maintained by the Go developers, along with the Go compiler. So there's a certain uniformity here which is a good thing - if features get added in Go version N, all of the: compiler, spec, `go/types` will be updated in sync for these new features. So it's all in one place, so to say